# How to pass an Arbitrary number of Parameterized Functions into constructor without compiler Warnings

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, variadic-functions

I have a `Test` class and a `Writer` class.

The `Writer` class does nothing but writes a string to a `StringBuilder`, nothing more. It also is allowed to have *"transformers"*. Meaning, in the constructor of the `Writer` class, you can pass any number of *lambda functions* to add additional processing to a string you are writing.

For example, like `String::toLowerCase`.

I want to be able to pass multiple of these *"transformers"* into the constructor of the writer.

*I have the below code:*

```
///Writer Class   Writer(Function<String, String>... someFunctions) {
abstract class Writer {
  Function<String, String>[] functions;

  Writer(Function<String, String>... someFunctions) {
    functions = someFunctions;
  }

}

///Test Class
    @Test
    default void WriterTestWriteThere() throws IOException {
        Writer writer = createWriter();
        writer.write("There");
        writer.close();

        assertEquals("There", getContents());
    }

    @Test
    default void WriterTestTwoTransformerFunctions() throws IOException {
        Writer writer = createWriter(
                text -> text.replaceAll("sometext", "s*****"),
                String::toUpperCase
        );
        writer.write("This is somethext!");
        writer.close();

        assertEquals("THIS IS S*****!", getContents());
    }
```

However, the compiler issues ***multiple warnings***.

`Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type` - error-message for the constructor of the `Writer` class.

`Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter`  - error-message for the `Test` class when the `Writer` instance is being created.

**I cannot use @SafeVarargs or @SuppressWarnings**

I have looked everywhere online, but cannot get a solid answer as to why these warnings are created, other than that the Java compiler does not like parameterized arguments being passed into a list. So, raises my question.

What can I use to fix it?

I need to be able to pass multiple functions into the writer class to transform the text as those functions want, and have no warnings. I have experimented with other Java utility classes other than Function, but I can't seem to find what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot use @SafeVarargs or @SuppressWarnings

As you probably know, *arrays* and *generics* don't play well together.

Arrays are covariant, i.e. method specifies `Number[]` - you can pass as an argument `Integer[]`, `Double[]`, `BigInteger[]`, etc.

Generics are invariant, i.e. if the declared parameter is a `List<Number>` - you can pass only `List<Number>`.

When you are passing an argument into the method that expects ***varargs*** they will be wrapped by an array. Therefore, the compiler isn't able to inure type-safety when you're mixing varargs and generics, and it warns you about possible heap pollution since it's impossible to verify whether the type of arguments will match.

You have to eliminate the need to create a generic array.

The best option is to combine all functions into a single one before passing into a constructor of `Writer`.

```
Function<String, String> f1 = String::toUpperCase;
Function<String, String> f2 = text -> text.replaceAll("somethext", "s*****");
Function<String, String> f3 = text -> text.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "&");

Function<String, String> combined = f1.andThen(f2).andThen(f3);
```

And `Writer` should have a field of type `Function<String, String>` but not, an array of functions.

```
public class Writer {
    private Function<String, String> function;

    public Writer(Function<String, String> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the List.of(functions) call, but in the end, this is what I ended up doing. Kind of dumb that the code has to look so repetitive now, but it is what it is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @h1dden Sorry I've found another way. Because both initial and resulting types of functions are identical, they are eligible to be combined into a single function. You need only one function in the `Writer`.

Comment: @h1dden that’s an artificial problem, unless you give a comprehensible explanation why you can’t use `@SafeVarargs` which exist precisely for solving this problem.

Comment: @Holger I am unable to use $SafeVarargs because it is unable to be used on a non-final version of my interfaces. I was using it on the final derived implementations but was hoping to find a method to circumvent the warning altogether for the other interfaces/classes.

Comment: @h1dden your question is showing a constructor. For a constructor, it doesn’t matter whether the class is final or not (and interfaces are not involved at all). Of course, the method or constructor receiving the array must assert that it is not going to perform any operation that can lead to heap pollution.